# Quiero comparar dos matrices en PHP

Tags: php

Quiero comparar dos matrices con PHP. No sé cómo hacerlo. Pongamos como ejemplo que ambas matrices son:

```
$carsPedro = array (
    array("Volvo",1,13000),
    array("BMW",3,13500),
    array("Saab",2,12000),
    array("Land Rover",4,15000)
  );

$carsMaria = array (
    array("Volvo",1,13000),
    array("BMW",2,13500),
    array("Saab",2,14000),
    array("Land Rover",4,15000)
  );
```

Las variables serían tipo de coche, antigüedad en años y precio. Básicamente quiero recorrer ambas matrices de forma simultánea y ver en qué datos hay diferencias (es decir, que no coinciden).

```
  for ($a=0; $a < $carsPedro  ; $a++) {
      echo $carsPedro[$a];
    for ($b=0; $b < $carsPedro ; $b++) { 
        echo $carsPedro[$a][$b];
    }
```

Por ahora estoy intentando que me muestre que recorre en cada momento del bucle, pero me da el error undefined offset y no sé por qué.
Yo entiendo que la solución podría ser algo como:

```
  for ($a=0; $a < $carsPedro  ; $a++) {
    for ($b=0; $b < $carsPedro ; $b++) { 
        if ($carsPedro[$a][$b]!==$carsMaria[$a][$b]){
           echo "Este dato no coincide";
    }
```

pero viendo los errores que me da, no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien o no. Gracias.

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

P.D. Quiero comparar todos con todos y que el programa me diga cuando los datos entre ambas matrices no coinciden.

Comment: En ambos `for` recorres la misma matriz, por lo que es imposible entender lo que quieres hacer. Pon un pequeño ejemplo de ambas matrices indicando lo que quieres comparar en sí.

Comment: Disculpa mi pesadez, pero debes ser claro cuando planteas una pregunta. Tienes sub-arrays con tres valores, ¿qué es lo que quieres comparar, uno de esos tres valores en específico, cuál de ellos, los tres valores, dos valores?

Comment: Lo aclaro, editando de nuevo la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado Sergio,
Tienes dos posibilidades.
Caso1: Quieres comparar los dos arreglos "todos con todos", es decir la salida de la función te indicará las diferencias de los elementos del array, mostrándote los elementos del primer arreglo que no están en el segundo array, el tercer array, etc. Esto se logra con la función array_diff(array1, array2, ...)

```
<?php
$arreglo1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$arreglo2 = array(2, 3, 5, 6, 7);
$resultado = array_diff($arreglo1, $arreglo2);
print_r($resultado);
?>
```

El Resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 4
)
```

Caso2: Por otro lado tenemos el siguiente caso, que se me imagina tu estás interesado.
También podemos comparar los elementos de un arreglo pivote con otro arreglo pero a diferencia del primer caso, éste sería "index por index", es decir, compara cada ubicación de un elemento, con el correspondiente del siguiente arreglo.

```
<?php
$arreglo1 = array('a','b','c','d','e');
$arreglo2 = array('a','b','f','g','e');
$resultado = array_diff_assoc($arreglo1, $arreglo2);
print_r($resultado);
?>
```

El resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
```

Espero que te sirva,
Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias. Al comparar ambas matrices ahora mismo me da un undefined offset. Supongo que para poder comparar igual tengo que hacer alguna conversión de datos o algo, no sé, alguna idea ¿? No comprendo a qué se debe este error.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes recorrer uno de los arrays y usar [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) para comparar si cada sub-array se encuentra en el otro.

Por ejemplo:

```
foreach ($carsPedro as $subArray){
    if (in_array($subArray, $carsMaria)) {
        print_r($subArray);
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Volvo
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 13000
)

Array
(
    [0] => Land Rover
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 15000
)
```

Comment: Básicamente yo lo que quiero es lo contrario. No ver cuál de un array se encuentra en otro, sino que por ejemplo, en este caso, que me de una salida que me diga: 1,1; 2,2; que en este caso son los datos que que no coinciden entre ambas matrices. Lo que no sé es cómo programarlo.

Comment: @Sergio, no entiendo lo de `1,1; 2,2`¿? Si quieres comparar lo contrario puedes ponerlo así: `if (!in_array($subArray, $carsMaria)) {`  y el `print_r` es a modo de prueba, ahí puedes sacar otra cosa, como el índice actual o lo que necesites.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si lo pones así: `foreach ($carsPedro as $k=>$subArray){ if (!in_array($subArray, $carsMaria)) { echo $k.PHP_EOL; } }` te va a imprimir `1` y `2` que son los índices que no coinciden.

Answer (score 1):

Tu planteamiento no era malo, solamente que estabas errando al tratar de determinar la longitud del **array** en el `for`:

```
for ($a=0; $a < $carsPedro  ; $a++) {
    for ($b=0; $b < $carsPedro ; $b++) { 
        if ($carsPedro[$a][$b]!==$carsMaria[$a][$b]){
           echo "Este dato no coincide";
        }
    }
}
```

Debería ser:

```
for ($a = 0; $a < count($carsPedro); $a++) {
    for ($b=0; $b < count($carsPedro[$a]); $b++) { 
        if ($carsPedro[$a][$b] !== $carsMaria[$a][$b]){
           echo "Este dato no coincide";
        }
    }
}
```

Con la función `count($carsPedro)` podemos obtener el número de filas que tiene la matriz y con `count($carsPedro[$a])` el número de columnas que tiene la fila que recorremos en ese momento.

No obstante, como te han señalado, **PHP** tiene funciones propias para operar entre **array** así que por medio de [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.p) o [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) puedes ahorrarte algunas líneas de código y el programar las iteraciones comparativas.